# Pull the logged in user credentials from windows: C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, smtp

I want to pull the logged in user credentials from windows and use it in C# program for authentication. I am using a SMTP code to send emails for failed indexes. And for 'from' where the email is coming I need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement you can use the [UserPrincipal.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get the UserPrincipalName if you are in an AD domain.